# How can I check if an actionFunction did not complete due to no internet connection?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

My problem is simple, i have an action function that sends data to the server every minute. I want to make it so that if the user loses connection, a message is displayed, I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function tryActionFunction() {
    try {
        MyActionFunction();
        $("#ErrContainer").hide();
    }
    catch(ex) {
        $("#ErrContainer").show();
    }
}
```

In chrome's console i get a POST net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED error, but the try-catch block doesn't seem to care.

Is there a way to capture the error to show to the user that he's lost connection?

Comment: I just found you can use navigator.onLine if you have an html5 page, but how would this be done if you weren't using html5?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think to achieve that is by using the [actionStatus](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionStatus.htm) component.

Also, not sure what you are trying to do here but notice that actionFunction will submit the form and, depending on the data on your page, that could be slow. For a more lightwheight option, you can use [Javascript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm).